# PIE root *(s)plei-: "to split, splice"?

Tags: proto-indo-european

I was reading [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=splice&searchmode=none)'s entry for **splice** {verb}:

> 1520s, originally a sailors' word, from Middle Dutch *splissen* "to splice" (Dutch *splitsen*), from Proto-Germanic *spli-*, from **PIE root *(s)plei- "to split, splice"** (see [flint](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=flint&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>   The Dutch word was borrowed in French as *épisser*.

**to split** and **to splice** are antonyms; so I'm confused. Is this PIE root a contronym?
If so, how did it become thus?

Footnote: I just discovered the pricelessness in [WARILY](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/12022/5306) learning PIE roots, for improving my English and French vocabulary. Please pardon this question if it's naive, but please do advise.

Comment: It's up to you whether it's a contronym or not, but it's not limited to that root. The [relevant phonosemantics of simplex words with the `SPL-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/spl.pdf) shows both splitting and splicing, depending on whether one's viewing input or output of the transformation referred to in the event -- which in turn mostly depends on which is relevant in the particular context where the word is used. Which can be pretty random.

Answer (score 1):

The OED (the uncredited source for most of the entries in etymonline) is a bit more cautious; its entry on “splice” says: “< Middle Dutch splissen, of doubtful origin, but perhaps related to split v.” Both “splice” and “split” are originally nautical terms, borrowed from Dutch. I do not see any great difficulty in the semantic development split > splice. You have to split a cable before you can splice it.